# Should landing pages for sensitive topics live on separate domains so that they can't hurt the SEO of the main site?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, private-blog-network

I've a new customer who previously worked with a marketing agency that created landing pages for his marketing campaigns. Imagine the customer's main website running on `example.org`.

The agency created all their landing pages that serve as target of campaigns about topics which may be judged 'critical' in terms of SEO (sexual topics, medicinal topics, etc.) on a separate domain, e.g.:

- Instead of running a marketing campaign about medicinal-topic-1 via a landing page hosted on `example.org/medicinal-topic-1`, they host that landing page with a brand new installation on `medicinal-topic-1.example`.

Their reasoning is that, if anything is judged as flagged / bad content in terms of SEO on `medicinal-topic-1.example`, that it won't affect the ranking on `example.org`.

Besides the obvious downsides of:

- Needing to configure a separate server / server directory for every single landing page.
- Needing to manage a separate WordPress installation for every single landing page (which is how they manage the content of their landing pages).
- Losing your visitor's trust in your brand when they drop on a somewhat random domain instead of dropping on your `example.org` domain.
- Data Tracking Configurations becoming an absolute mess due to this, especially with the upcoming third-party cookie deprecation.
- Actually not gaining the traffic of your campaigns on your main website.

Is hosting this content on separate domains good practice to avoid bad content on landing pages hurting the SEO of the main site?

Comment: To put a name to it, this strategy is the "Private Blog Network" strategy.

Comment: Is it really worth it the extra-effort, opposing all of the above-mentioned downsides and of course the extra-cost of management per additional domain? I cannot find any cool case studies / examples online..

Comment: You also need to worry about who owns the content.  Is the SEO agency producing the content for you as a work-for-hire? Or are they planning to own the content and have it link to you only as long as you are paying for their services?  I've seen SEO agencies want to host off-site content primarily for that reason, so it is something to watch out for.

Comment: The thing is, it would be a PBN strategy if the landingpages had backlinks to the main website / domain. But the only link to the main domain they have is the one in the footer, about the root address `example.org`. Does that already go under PBN for you? Because they simply argued that they "have better click-through rates if the campaign target is a landingpage hosted on a separate domain, vs a subsite on the main domain, given the same content & page speed". That statement makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Oh wow just read your last comments; that really happens? Now that would be ridiculous, thanks for the heads up!